# Which css style has least effect on an element?

Tags: html, css

Today I was trying to create a dummy css rule for testing and investigation.

```
.dummy {
  some-style : somevalue;
}
```

Ideally the class should have no visible effect.  I want to be able to apply the class to elements but cause the least visible effect possible on any elements it is applied to.  For example

`<div class="dummy">` should look and behaves as much as possible like `<div>`

I did not want the class to be empty.  Can anyone suggest a style that I could add to the class that would have the least visible impact when applied to a general html element?  I can't think of anything completely harmless.

UPDATE: I wanted to add the style to some existing html.  The reason was to use the style as a marker for diagnostic purposes.  It would help me see when and where styles and stylesheets were getting loaded/cached and where and why some styles were getting overridden, sometimes by the browser defaults which seemed odd.  At the time I didn't have exclusive use of the system I was working on so I wanted something that was going to be invisible to other users but I could see in Developer Tools.

UPDATE 2 : the html/css wasn't written by me and I didn't have my own environment in which to work. I was trying to investigate some problems in-situ in someone else's system.  I had tried using DevTools in the browser but wasn't getting anywhere with that.  I wanted to be able to make some small changes to their html/css to aid my diagnostics.  I didn't want them to have any obvious effect on the system for other people (except in DevTools, viewed by me).

It was a Wordpress site and they only had two environments, one for live and one for testing.  I was working with the test system.  There were other people testing at the time, though mainly checking content.

The real thorny problem was why was the font-size in the calendar widget much larger than everything else on the site?  Inspecting using DevTools I could see the font-size style was getting overridden by the browser default style when it seemed to me there were other css selectors that should have taken precedence.  It looked bizarre.  In the end it turned out to be a missing !DOCTYPE tag in the html.  So nothing to do with the css itself.

I didn't like this way of working, fiddling in someone's system, but there wasn't much else to do and it did help to resolve the problem for them.

Hopefully I don't have to do this again, but ever since I have been wondering what was the most harmless style that I could have used?

I thought I would ask here as there must be people who know CSS better than me.

Comment: `opacity: 1`? That won't have much effect unless you already have some transparent items.

Comment: You could use a definition that describes a default value for the `<div>`, something like `position:static`, `display:block`, `border:none`, `margin:0`, etc.

Comment: Not sure what you're doing this for but it sounds fishy, what's the point? Why do you have to declare any styles at all? What's the goal here?

Comment: Wesley - I was trying to figure out why and when styles were being applied in a site.  At the time I didn't have sole use of the system I was experimenting with so I wanted to be able to add some styles and classes for diagnostic purposes that I could see in the dev tools on the browser but would be transparent to others users on the site.

Comment: Would someone explain why the question is down voted?  Explain and next time I can make it better.

Comment: Not sure, but maybe because the question seems a bit odd. Are you sure applying styles are the best way? My first thought was that if you have to track these applied CSS properties using the Dev Tools anyways, why not use the other features the Dev Tools are shipped with? I mean instead of actually altering the site contents?

Comment: The _Inspector_, _Style Editor_ and _Network_ tabs in Firefox Dev Tools as well as the _Elements_, _Sources_ and _Application_ tabs in Chrome Dev Tools should all give you a pretty good overview of loaded stylesheets and their contents.

Comment: agrm - I was using Inspector, Network Sources etc but wasn't making any progress.  That is why I wanted to start poking some new css into the html to see if I could make some progress again.

Answer (score 6):

**UPDATE:**

You can simply use a non-existing rule - it will be ignored by the browser => no effect.

```
.dummy{
    nothing: none;
}
```

---

**OLD ANSWER:**

You can use this:

```
.dummy{
    min-width: 0;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this change the behaviour of an element that already had a minimum size?  It would now shrink down to nothing rather then sticking at the previous value.

Comment: So you want some CSS code which will do nothing in any case...
It's impossible, you can always find a problem

Comment: I am asking what CSS would have the _least_ impact.  Do nothing would be have been ideal but as you say I think that would probably be impossible.  Thanks for your suggestion, I appreciate it.  Are there any other candidates for least impact?

Comment: @PaulD Just updated my answer, it took only 6 years, but I found one for you ;)

Comment: thank you!  I seems so obvious, I can't believe now that such a simple solution got overlooked for so long.  I think there is a lesson in that somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

In principle, for any property you can have an arrangement like this:

```
div {
  some-style : a-valid-value-for-some-style;
}

.dummy {
  some-style : a-different-valid-value-for-some-style;
}
```

And `.dummy`'s style will have an effect, no matter what some-style is.

Your best bet is to make use of CSS variables. These are custom properties and start with a double hyphen. so

```
.dummy {
   --dummy-style: foo;
}
```

will make `--dummy-style` a property with value "foo". So long as you don't employ the variable as the value in another property, it will have no visible effect.

Comment: An unused css variable would work but I really wanted something that will be pre-defined in the brower's default style.  One of the things I was looking at was why did the browser's default style sometimes take precedence over an applied style.

Comment: @PaulD - You should probably ask a new question along those lines, then. Do you have a particular example of that happening? There's several reasons that can happen, or can appear to happen. Without a concrete example, it can be hard to identify which one applies.

Comment: I have added some more background in the question.  The original issue that led to this question is now solved, but I'm still curious to know if there is a low impact style out there that I can't think of.

Comment: I have the problem as the op. I have a css animation triggered from css and I want to get how much of the animation is completed via js. I am updating css vars in keyframes, but when I get the computed value of that var via js, I always get the initial value, whereas if I apply that var to `z-index` and then get the computed `z-index`, I get how much of the animation is completed.

Comment: The custom css property is the way to go. I use `.some_class { --moot: moot; }`

Answer (score 0):

If you just need anything beeing set you could assign rules that are default anyway. For block elements like **div** set

```
.block-class { display: block; }
```

And for inline elements like **span**

```
.inline-class { display: inline; }
```

Of course it could be an issue doing so in some rare cases but in general it's quite harmless I guess.

Comment: I really wanted something that could be applied across a range of elements.  Also applying display: block; to a div with display: none; would make it visible again.

Comment: Ah ok, I thought it is just for a quick test. Looking at it that way there is no rule that not could produce issues I fear. Btw I can't imagine that the browser styles override the styles you set in your css. Maybe you go with the comment suggestion `opacity: 1;`from cms_dev - but like said that could produce issues as well.